# Looking to retrieve user's groups in SharePoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, spservices

I am running SharePoint Foundation 2010. I have a claims based site setup to use a trusted token provider. I am passing it a set of claims that determine the user's group. They look similar to this: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group. On my SharePoint end I have created some SharePoint groups and users to these SharePoint groups through the claims groups. The permissions are working great and I can manipulate them however.

The issue is I would like to get these users' SharePoint groups from code (preferably jQuery) I have attempted to use the SPServices but haven't had much luck. For some reason I can only obtain the user's group if they have been directly added (not added through their group) I followed this tutorial http://azzu-sheikh.blogspot.com/2013/05/jquery-spservices-to-get-current-user.html and it works well if the user has been directly added.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [UserGroup.GetGroupCollectionFromUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772552%28v=office.12%29.aspx) from [Users and Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772647%28v=office.12%29.aspx) SOAP service, you could retrieve groups of which the specified user is a member via CSOM.

### How to retrieve groups of which the specified user is a member via CSOM (JavaScript)

```
function getUserGroups(loginName, Success,Error) {

   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var allGroups = web.get_siteGroups();
   context.load(allGroups,'Include(Title,Users)');

   context.executeQueryAsync(
        function(sender, args) {
            var userGroups = findUserGroups(loginName,allGroups);         
            Success(userGroups);
        },
        Error
   );


    function findUserGroups(loginName,groups)
    {
         var userGroups = []; 
         var groupsEnumerator = groups.getEnumerator();
         while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
             var group = groupsEnumerator.get_current();
             if(isUserInGroup(loginName,group)){
                 userGroups.push(group);
             }
         }
         return userGroups;
     }

     function isUserInGroup(loginName,group)
     {
         var users = group.get_users();
         var userInGroup = false;
         var usersEnumerator = users.getEnumerator();
         while (usersEnumerator.moveNext()) {
             var user = usersEnumerator.get_current();
             if (user.get_loginName().toLowerCase() == loginName.toLowerCase()) {
                  userInGroup = true;
                  break;
             }
         }
         return userInGroup;
      }

}
```

Example:

```
var userLogin = 'domain\\userLogin';
getUserGroups(userLogin,function (groups) {
    console.log('User belongs to the following groups:');
    for(var i = 0; i < groups.length;i++) {
        console.log(groups[i].get_title());
    }    
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log('Error:' + args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. What is interesting is this pulls a different set of groups that what is in the "Check Permissions" in the Site Permissions page. From that page I can see 5 SharePoint groups for a particular user, but only one shows up (a different group) from this code snippet. Any ideas?

Comment: Good question, function getUserGroups returns groups of which the specified user is a member. Check permissions page returns permissions levels given to the user.

Comment: true, but it does list the groups the particular user is a part of.

Comment: Given through the "___" group.